# Odoo 15 Search non-stored compute value that depends on search_count of many2one field

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to display a view with certain products that have multiple BoM's. I've created a computed field that labels which records should be displayed. I'm trying to create a search function so that the records in interest can be displayed as a filter but am having trouble creating the function.

Currently trying to append record.id's of interest into a list and returning the list within the search domain but that is not working. Any help would be much appreciated. Please see code below and thanks in advance!

I tried the following code but it returns an empty data list. I think there's something wrong with how I'm getting the id of the current record and appending it to the list that is returned.

```
class products_ppa_bom_check(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['product.template']
    ppa_multi_bom = fields.Selection([
        ('true', 'True'),
        ('false', 'False'),
        ('na', 'Not Applicable')], 
        string="PPA Multi BOM Check", compute='_compute_ppa_multi_bom',
        search='_search_ppa_multi_bom')
    
    def _compute_ppa_multi_bom(self):
        for record in self:
            count = record.env['mrp.bom'].search_count(['|', ('product_tmpl_id', '=', record.id), ('byproduct_ids.product_id.product_tmpl_id', '=', record.id)])
            if (count > 1) and ('PPA' in str(record.default_code)):
                record.ppa_multi_bom = 'true'
            elif (count == 1) and ('PPA' in str(record.default_code)):
                record.ppa_multi_bom = 'false'
            else: record.ppa_multi_bom = 'na'
  
    def _search_ppa_multi_bom(self, operator, value):
        ids = []
        for record in self:
            count = record.env['mrp.bom'].search_count(['|', ('product_tmpl_id', '=', record.id), ('byproduct_ids.product_id.product_tmpl_id', '=', record.id)])
            if (count > 1) and ('PPA' in str(record.default_code)):
                ids = ids.append(record.id)
        return[('id', 'in', ids)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a filter in products with `=` operator, you can use the below code which I already tested:

You can use `bom_count` field rather than use `search_count` method

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _


class products_ppa_bom_check(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['product.template']

    ppa_multi_bom = fields.Selection([
        ('true', 'True'),
        ('false', 'False'),
        ('na', 'Not Applicable')],
        string="PPA Multi BOM Check", compute='_compute_ppa_multi_bom',
        search='_search_ppa_multi_bom')

    def _compute_ppa_multi_bom(self):
        for record in self:
            if (record.bom_count > 1) and ('PPA' in str(record.default_code)):
                record.ppa_multi_bom = 'true'
            elif (record.bom_count == 1) and ('PPA' in str(record.default_code)):
                record.ppa_multi_bom = 'false'
            else:
                record.ppa_multi_bom = 'na'

    def _search_ppa_multi_bom(self, operator, value):
        true_ids = self.env['product.template'].search([]).filtered(
            lambda x: x.bom_count > 1 and 'PPA' in str(x.default_code)).ids
        false_ids = self.env['product.template'].search([]).filtered(
            lambda x: x.bom_count == 1 and x.default_code and 'PPA' in x.default_code).ids
        if value == 'true':
            ids = true_ids
        elif value == 'false':
            ids = false_ids
        else:
            all_ids = self.env['product.template'].search([]).ids
            ids = list(set(all_ids) - set(true_ids + false_ids))
        return [('id', 'in', ids)]
```

To add filter to search view:

```
 <record id="product_template_search_view_inherit_bom" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.search.inherit.bom</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//filter[@name='consumable']" position="after">
                    <separator/>
                    <filter string="Multi BOM" name="ppa_multi_bom" domain="[('ppa_multi_bom', '=', 'true')]"/>
                    <filter string="One BOM" name="ppa_one_bom" domain="[('ppa_multi_bom', '=', 'false')]"/>
                    <filter string="NA BOM" name="ppa_na_bom" domain="[('ppa_multi_bom', '=', 'na')]"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```